# Hover in input fields

Tags: html, css

I have got an input firm and one problem. I position my button with a negative margin-left (delete space between inputs) because I need it to look like a whole, only the button should have border round. If I do not use a negative margin and remove the right border of the text field, I get a bit of empty space between the inputs. The problem is that when you click on the text box, I do not see the hover on the right side, how can this be fixed? In the end, I should get the same as in the photo (round border on the buttons on all sides, without a space between the button and the text field), only with the correct hover

[image]

```css
#text-area {
   height: 11px;
}

#button-area {
   margin-left:-10px;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text here" id="text-area">
<input type="submit" placeholder="enter text here" id="button-area" value="Find">
```

Comment: "The problem is that when you click on the text box, I do not see the hover on the right side" - could you rephrase this sentence? It is not clear what is your problem...

Comment: Provide a working code snippet where we can see what you mean exactly.

Comment: i think u confused with hovering and foucing.. Try to ask question clearly

Comment: @sinisake i think he meant when he hovers the text area the button should have a hover effect aswell

Comment: @Hash, i thought so, too, but, really can't be sure... And, if so, should hover effect be applied for both inputs: 1) when text field is hovered 2) when button is hovered? In second case, some js will be mandatory, i think...

Answer (score 2):

According to what I have understood from your question, my CSS code for this problem looks somewhat like this.

```css
#text-area {
  /* height: 11px;
  */
  border: 2px solid rgba(92, 91, 91, 0.589);
  border-right: none;  
  margin-right: none;
  padding-right: none;
}

#button-area {
  margin-left: -4.8%;
  padding-top: 0.0625rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.0625rem;
  background-color: #8cc425;
  border: 0.125rem solid rgba(92, 91, 91, 0.589);
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
}
#button-area:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text here" id="text-area">
<input type="submit" placeholder="enter text here" id="button-area" value="Find" >
```

You are free to experiment with this code.
If you have any doubts regarding this comment in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your desired result?

```css
.formthing {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#text-area {
  border: none;
}

#button-area {
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: -2px;
  background-color: #CDFF65;
  height: 23px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.formthing:hover, 
.formthing:hover > #button-area {
  border: 1px solid #5794BF;
}
```

```html
<div class="formthing">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter text here" id="text-area">
  <input type="submit" placeholder="enter text here" id="button-area" value="Find">
</div>
```

I removed the `border` of the `input`, created a new `div` around the `input` and the `button` and did some styling with `border` and `border-radius`.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/chaitanya207/svh46aL1/

```css
.find-box{
    width:450px;
    position:relative;
}
.find-box input[type="text"]{
    width:450px;
    border:2px solid #9f9f9f;
    height:70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-indent:10px;
    outline:none;
}
.find-box input[type="submit"]{
    width:100px;
    background:#cdff65;
    border:none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:18px;
    height:72px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    right:-2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="find-box">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter text here" id="text-area">
  <input type="submit" placeholder="enter text here" id="button-area" value="Find">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The :focus selector is used to select the element that has focus.

ie:- The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

it works, when we go in input to write something

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

  <form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```